# Unable to click on Select link present in last column of web table

Tags: cypress

I want to search Seller and have to click on select link for selected one. When I type seller name, it shows only record for selected seller.

[image: web table with search text box]

I tried with following code, its not working. Can anyone please help

```js
    cy.get('input[name="search"]',{ timeout: 10000 }).type(this.data1.vehicle1_seller1)
    //cy.wait(6000)

     Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 10000);
     cy.get('td[class="span-3"] div').each(($el, index, $list) => {

     if ($el.text().includes('STB002')) {
        // cy.contains("Select").eq(index).click()
     cy.get('.span-1-5 > div > a > span').contains('select').eq(index).click({force:true})
   }
}
```

[image: only one row is displayed after search]

this is the DOM structure >

[image: DOM structure]

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="span-3">
        <div title="06V001">06V001</div> == $0
      </td>
      <td>
        <div title="06 Vauxhall Ormskirk">06 Vauxhall Ormskirk</div>
      </td>
      <td class="span-1-5">
        <div>
          <a id="link57" href="./wicket/page?7-1.-seller-table-body-rows-10-cells-3-cell-link"> 
            <span>select</span> 
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">

    </tr>
    <tr class="even">

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I recommend adding DOM structure for element(s) as text instead of a screenshot, sharing any error outputs, and clear description of the problem. It will be easier for others to help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the exact issue is? From your description, I'm not sure if the issue is that you aren't seeing the correct row, can't select the correct row, or something else. If there is an error message related to what you're trying to do, please add that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML table is set out in rows and cells, exactly as you see it on the screen.

Your test is searching for the ***cell*** containing the text, but really you want to search for the ***row*** containing the text, then get the `select` button of that row.

The basic test would be

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'STB002')
  .within(() => {
    // now inside the row
    cy.contains('span', 'select').click()
  })
```

The next problem is the car `STB002` isn't on the first page, so you won't find it straight after loading.

Maybe use the search box to load that row (as you have in one screen-shot). I can't say what that code is, because the DOM picture doesn't include the search box.

Comment: Thanks @Paolo. it worked with your suggestion